# Why we're getting random CORS error on Amazon Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We're using cloudfront to serve our assets (images, fonts, translations json files) stored in s3. We're using the configuration in the images. We noticed that we get CORS error randomly and it's a bit frustrating coz we were unable to replicate the issue. What could be wrong in this configuration that might cause it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612261/intermittent-403-cors-errors-access-control-allow-origin-with-cloudfront-using. Hope it helps