# Getting CORS error on CloudFront + hls.js

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront, m3u8, hls.js

### Scenario

I am serving my hls videos on S3 with Cloudfront and play them with hls.js library

### Problem

Sometimes I am getting CORS errors, the weird part is if I disable cache in the browser, it's working fine, but when it's use the cached version it returns the CORS error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://a-subdomin.cloudfront.net/myvideo.m3u8' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

### Configs

Here is my Cloudfront behavior config
[image]

and here is my S3 CORS config
[image]

I tried many ways, but I don't know what is the problem, I am thinking maybe it's about hls.js library!

Comment: Also I checked with curl and everything seems ok and I returned `access-control-allow-origin`, `access-control-allow-credentials`, `access-control-allow-methods`

Comment: And it seems it's only happening on chrome, not sure btw

Comment: Is the OPTIONS HTTP method enabled on the cache behavior?

Comment: Yes it's enabled too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue, it's only happening for Chromium based browsers, and to fix this issue **you should send the vary header in non CORS requests as well**.

in AWS you can use Lambda functions to do it, here is the example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57189635/3970050

Chromium issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409090

AWS issue: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=342401&tstart=0